# Having trouble updating ng-repeat list after I submit form, scope issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a form to submit a new message to the conversation list.
I want to update the list to reflect the changes without user having to refresh the browser.(*after refreshing the page I can see the new msg and it renders like how I want it to but I want to Ajaxify this)

```
  $scope.sendMessage = function(){
    console.log($scope.messages);
    Message.saveMessage($scope.newMsg,$stateParams.id)
      .then(function(data){
        $scope.messages.push(data) ;
      })
  }
```

when I logged messages $scope.messages is '[]'
so i am guessing there is a behavior of $scope that I'm not aware of.

Here is my code

## view layout (ui-view is here)

```
%body#conversations-index{'ng-app' => 'convoWidget', 'ng-cloak'=>'true'}
  %main{'ng-controller' => 'convoCtrl'}
    =render file: 'layouts/navbar'
    %div.container
      %div.all-content
        %div.row
          -# start of tabs on the left side
          %div{class: 'col s4'}
            %div.collection.convo-tab-container
              %a.collection-item.avatar{'ui-sref'=>'show({id: \'{{convo._id.$oid}}\'})','ng-repeat'=>'convo in convos'}
                %img.circle{'ng-src'=>'{{otherUserPic(convo)}}'}
                %span
                  {{ otherUserName(convo) }} &nbsp;
                %p
                  {{ lastMsgPreview(convo) }}
                %p
                  {{ lastMsgCreatedDate(convo) | date: 'MMM d, y   hh:mm'}}
          -# start of view messages area
          %div{class: 'col s8 msg-container'}
            %div.msg-show-container{'autoscroll'=>true,'scroll'=>'messages'}
              %div{'ui-view' => true,'autoscroll'=>true}
            -# where you create new messages
            %div.new-msg-container
              %form
                %div{class: 'col s9 textbox'}
                  %textarea{'ng-model'=>'newMsg'}
                %div{class: 'col s3 btnbox'}
                  %input.btn.btn-large{'ng-click'=>'sendMessage()','type'=>'submit','value'=>'reply'}
```

## ng-repeat here

```
<ul class='collection' ng-init='getClickedConvo();scrollBottom()'>
  <li class='collection-item avatar' ng-repeat='message in messages' ng-switch="$last">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="msg-profile col s8 valign-wrapper">
        <img ng-src="{{ creatorPic(message) }}" class="circle valign" />
        <span class="valign">
          {{ creatorName(message) }} &nbsp;
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="col s4">
        <span>{{ msgCreatedDate(message) | date: 'MMM d, y   hh:mm' }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row msg-body">
      <p>
        {{ message.body }}
      </p>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="true" id='bottom'>&nbsp;</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

## ctrl & etc

```
convoWidget.controller('convoCtrl',['$scope','$http','Conversation','$stateParams','Message','$location','$anchorScroll',function($scope,$http,Conversation,$stateParams,Message,$location,$anchorScroll){

  $scope.currentUserId
  $scope.convos = [] ;
  $scope.messages = [] ;
  $scope.defaultPicUrl = 'http://i.imgur.com/P25qqYM.png'

  $scope.scrollBottom = function(){
    var sheight = $('.msg-show-container')[0].scrollHeight ;
    $('.msg-show-container').scrollTop(sheight) ;
    $( '.msg-show-container').animate({
      scrollTop: sheight
    }, 500);
  }

  $scope.getClickedConvo = function(){
    var convoId, promise ;
    convoId = $stateParams.id ;
    Conversation.getConvo(convoId)
      .then(function(data){
        $scope.messages = data;
      })
  }

  $scope.sendMessage = function(){
    console.log($scope.messages);
    Message.saveMessage($scope.newMsg,$stateParams.id)
      .then(function(data){
        $scope.messages.push(data) ;
      })
  }

// =====================================

  $scope.otherUserName = function(convo){
    var other, fullName ;
    if(convo.author_id.$oid === $scope.currentUserId){
      other = convo.recipient
    }else if(convo.recipient_id.$oid === $scope.currentUserId){
      other = convo.author
    }
    fullName =  other.firstname + ' ' + other.lastname ;
    if(fullName.trim().length == 0){
      return 'Anonymous User'
    }
    return fullName ;
  }

  $scope.otherUserPic = function(convo){
    var picUrl ;
    if(convo.author_id.$oid === $scope.currentUserId){
      if(picUrl = convo.recipient.profile.avatar.small.url){
        return picUrl
      }else{
        return $scope.defaultPicUrl
      }
    }else if(convo.recipient_id.$oid === $scope.currentUserId){
      if(picUrl = convo.author.profile.avatar.small.url){
        return picUrl
      }else{
        return $scope.defaultPicUrl
      }
    }
  }

  $scope.lastMsgPreview = function(convo){
    var content, limit = 30 ;
    content = convo.messages[convo.messages.length - 1].body
    if(content.length > limit){
      return content.slice(0,limit-1) + ' ' + '...' ;
    }
    return content ;
  }

  $scope.lastMsgCreatedDate = function(convo){
    var msg = convo.messages[convo.messages.length - 1]
    return new Date(Date.parse(msg.created_at));
  }

  $scope.creatorPic = function(msg){
    var picUrl ;
    picUrl = msg.creator.profile.avatar.small.url;
    if(picUrl){
      return picUrl ;
    }else{
      return $scope.defaultPicUrl ;
    }
  }

  $scope.msgCreatedDate = function(msg){
    return new Date(Date.parse(msg.created_at));
  }

  $scope.creatorName = function(msg){
    var creator, creatorId, creatorFullName
    creator = msg.creator;
    creatorId = creator._id.$oid;
    creatorFullName = creator.firstname + ' ' + creator.lastname;

    if(creatorId === $scope.currentUserId){
      return 'Me' ;
    }else{
      var fullName = creatorFullName.trim.length == 0 ? 'Anonymous User' : creatorFullName ;
      return fullName ;
    }
  }

  $scope.msgContent = function(msg){
    return msg.body
  }

  $scope.refresh = function(){
    Conversation.getLatestConvos()
      .then(function(data){
        $scope.convos = data.conversations ;
        $scope.currentUserId = data.current_user ;
      })
  }
  $scope.refresh();
}])

convoWidget.directive('convoTab',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'convo-tab.html',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      convoObj: '=',
      convoId: '=',
      otherUserName: '&',
      otherUserPic: "&",
      lastMsgPreview: '&',
      lastMsgCreatedDate: '&'
    }
  }
})

convoWidget.directive('msg',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'msg.html',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      creatorPic: '&',
      msgObj: '=',
      msgCreatedDate: '&',
      dateFormat: '@',
      creatorName: '&',
      msgContent: '&'
    }
  }
})

convoWidget.directive('scroll', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.$watchCollection(attr.scroll, function(newVal) {
        $timeout(function() {
         element[0].scrollTop = element[0].scrollHeight;
        });
      });
    }
  }
});

convoWidget.factory('Message',['$http','$q',function($http,$q){
  return {
    saveMessage: function(body,conversationId){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http({
        method:'POST',
        url:'/conversations/' + conversationId  + '/messages',
        data: JSON.stringify({conversation_id: conversationId, message:{body: body}} ),
        headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
      })
      .success(function(data,st,headers,config){
        deferred.resolve(data);
      })
      return deferred.promise ;
    }
  }
}])
```

Thank you for reading 
any help would be great!
Happy coding

Comment: put a console.log after  $scope.messages.push(data) ; to see how is the data you get back

Comment: i get [newObj] in return. it got rid of all the objects from the previous scope. I am expecting [oldObj,oldOBj,oldObj,newObj].  some how i lost the scope

Comment: what do you have in newObj ? i want trhe structure of your data

Comment: {id: 1534523, body: 'testing', updated_at: "2015-07-03T01:44:01.693Z",created_at:"2015-07-03T01:44:01.693Z",conversation_id:6234562}

Comment: It seems good, can you try to add $scope.$apply(); after your push ?

Comment: already in $digest. I dunno why i loose the original scope after ng-click